# 301 redirect will not work with %20 in url

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am trying to create this redirect:

```
Redirect /commercial%20work.html http://nataliearriolaphotography.com/fine-art-photography-prints.html
```

The problem is that when I first created this page I left a space in the file name. In other words it was "`/commercial work.html`". In chrome and safari the url reads as above with the `%20` in place of the space, but when I create this redirect it does not work. I have also tried the following:

```
Redirect /commercial work.html http://nataliearriolaphotography.com/fine-art-photography-prints.html
```

This does not work either. It causes a server error page to appear. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try adding quotes. So

```
Redirect "/commercial work.html" http://nataliearriolaphotography.com/fine-art-photography-prints.html
```

Comment: Gerben, thanks for the answer, but that doesn't work either. It causes a server error page to appear. Maybe it has something to do with fatcow? Acutally I missed the quotes. Let me try it again! Sorry!

Comment: @evangelion3258 what do you mean by fatcow?

Comment: You're welcome. In return, please mark it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am trying t get it work, but this case isn't working with quotes, gives 500 Error (tried multiple variations)
`RedirectMatch 301 ^/2012 files/(.*)$ /archives/old-website/2012 files/$1`

Comment: @Yatko is the `mod_alias` module loaded? Also try `RedirectMatch 301 ^/2012\ files/(.*)$ /archives/old-website/2012\ files/$1`

Comment: @Gerben: I am also troubling with this. Your solution is not working for me. What  can issue is? Is there any server issue?

Comment: @VishalChanana You might want to clear your cache and then try again. I had the same issue...

Comment: @Gerben What would the Rewrite equivalent be? I tried the Rewrite, but got errors all the time; it wanted to redirect to the root of the server instead of the domain.. not sure why it didn't work...

Answer (score 2):

Put the page name in quotes should do it, for example:

```
Redirect 301 "/commercial work.html" http://nataliearriolaphotography.com/fine-art-photography-prints.html
```